# Package apr-1 was not found in the pkg-config search path

Tags: chef-infra, centos6, chef-recipe

I'm but a junior front end web dev who's boss is in France for a week, and I have a centos server that isn't functioning as it should. The extent of my knowledge here is that I'm supposed to run vagrant provision and start working on the dev site that's linked to my app. :(

I think I've found the source of the problem, but I can't figure out what the error actually means. Anyone recognize this? (PKG_CONFIG_PATH isn't defined in the env when I ssh into the box.)

Error message:

```
Package apr-1 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
==> Perhaps you should add the directory containing `apr-1.pc'
==> to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
==> No package 'apr-1' found
==> cannot open /httpd/build/config_vars.mk: No such file or directory at /usr/sbin/apxs line 201.
```

`http.rb` file (one of a few identical scripts scattered across the project) where the error may have originated.
[image: The source of all my troubles. (I think.)]

Answer (score 1):

apr is the Apache Portable Runtime, basically a library of C code that is reused by a lot of Apache related projects (mostly Apache HTTPD and it's modules like oy have here). You would generally install it via your system packages like `libapr1` and the associated development headers `libapr1-dev` for Ubuntu. I don't have a CentOS machine handy to check package names there but I'm sure it's similar.